# Akka HTTP does not handle ValidationRejections, instead throws require java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed

Tags: akka-http

I have the following test

```
"adding a nominee with empty fields  " should {
  "be rejected" in {
    val nominee = NomineeReq("Saving", "", "***", "29-08-1984", "Friend", "***", Some("***"), "1234", "****", "Some state", Some("****"))
    Post("/v1/nominees/", nominee)
      .withHeaders(List(httpHeaders.Authorization(httpHeaders.OAuth2BearerToken("4abf9af4-1910-437c-8510-1c8d4222901b")))) ~> Route.seal(route) ~> check {
      status should be(StatusCodes.BadRequest)
    }
  }
}
```

And the following service code 
`case class NomineeReq(
     val account_type: String,
     val account_subtype: String,
     val name: String,
     val dob: String,
     val relationship: String,
     val address1: String,
     val address2: Option[String],
     val pin_code: String,
     val city: String,
     val state: String,
     val email: Option[String]){
  require(account_type.nonEmpty, "account_type")
  require(account_subtype.nonEmpty, "account_subtype =")
  require(name.nonEmpty, "name.")
  require(relationship.nonEmpty, "relationship")
  require(address1.nonEmpty, "address1")
  require(pin_code.nonEmpty, "pin_code")
  require(city.nonEmpty, "city")
  require(state.nonEmpty, "state")
  require(email.nonEmpty, "email")
} 
/**some code**/
(post & entity(as[NomineeReq])) { nominee =>
            complete(setNominee(user.userId, nominee))
}`

When I run it, I get the following error - "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: account_subtype =
[info]     at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)"

As per [doc][1], this

[1]: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.3/scala/http/routing-dsl/case-class-extraction.html "doc" this should result in a ValidationRejections, which will be translated by the default rejection handler to a BadRequest

Comment: The documentation is about another `as` so it's not exactly the same. But you are still right that this should work. Could you file an issue with a reproducer?

Comment: Btw. WDYM with 'I get the following error - "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: account_subtype = [info] at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)'? Is it logged? Or where does the exception end up?